# alternatives/options for overrightarrow

Tags: arrows

I want to type something similar to $\overrightarrow v$. To me the arrow looks too big in length and too wide in size of tip (especially at enlarged fontsize like 18). As if $v$ is overshadowed by the arrow. What are my my options and/or alternatives?  As a second consideration I look for something that is also available in Matlab.

Comment: What is wrong with `$\vec v$`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the most commonly used vector notation commands in LaTeX. For Matlab vectors I have found this link for example (the use of `\bar{v}`):
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/21984-tex-latex-math-mode-symbols-in-legends-and-labels-in-matlab-figures

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,verbatim,mathabx}
\usepackage[b]{esvect}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim} The arrow of the question.
\end{verbatim}
\[\overrightarrow{v}\]
\begin{verbatim} With esvect package option [b].
\end{verbatim}
\[\vv{v}\]
\begin{verbatim} Using \overline{v}.
\end{verbatim}
\[\overline{v}\]
\begin{verbatim} Using \widebar{v} with mathabx package.
\end{verbatim}
\[\widebar{v}\]

\begin{verbatim} Using usual \vec{v}.
\end{verbatim}
\[\vec{v}\]

\begin{verbatim} Using usual \bar{v}.
\end{verbatim}
\[\bar{v}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't mention it!